# Spatial correlated covariates with spatial correlated response

Tags: regression, spatial

I like to estimate a linear regression model in a Panel data set using a fixed effects specification. 
From the data (and theory) I know that my response variable ($Y$) is spatial correlated. The same is true for some of my covariates ($X$). The values of covariates are nearly identical in nearby regions but differences are increasing with distance. 
Is it a proper solution to apply a Spatial Durbin Model in this case (e.g. LeSage/Parent (2009))?

The model would be: $Y = WY + WX + X + \epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ is normal distributed) 
Relying on theoretical background, I am quite sure how the spatial weights ($W$) should look like. Would this kind of model solve the issues of spatial autocorrelation in my data? If the residuals of the model do not show any signs of spatial correlation (Morans-$I$ test), would that imply that the model is valid?
What would be a proper solution if only the covariates ($X$) are spatially correlated and not the Response ($Y$)?